# Hot plugging an additional node in OpenMPI cluster

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, openmpi

Is it possible to hot plug an additional node (host) into a working OpenMPI app? We're talking about production environment where we cannot afford even a 5 second downtime.
There are two scenarios I'm interested in:

1. We just would like to enhance the computing power by adding one more broadcast listener.
2. A node died, the master node handles it well and reassigns the task to somebody else. The system administrator comes in, restarts the dead node and plugs it back into the cluster.

Which platform independent MPI implementation would be best for the scenario above? OpenMPI is not a must here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI-2 -- any implementation -- does allow dynamic processes, and in fact *adding* processes is currently much more feasible than removing processes.  You can use [MPI_COMM_SPAWN](http://www.ualberta.ca/AICT/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/doc/mpich2/www3/MPI_Comm_spawn.html) to launch a new process with a given executable, and that returns an intracommunicator that can be used to communicate between the old (original) processes.

The tricks here are -- nothing will automatically detect the new node.   You'll have to have some process keeping an eye out for them, `SPAWN` something on them.  If the new nodes will just be listeners to the master node, that's probably the best case, as only the master node really needs to know about it.   The invocation to ensure the spawn happens on the new node and not somewhere else will be done through the `info` argument to spawn, and may be implementation dependant.

Comment: How do I add a new hostname to the host list if the system is already running? Just calling SPAWN will spawn a process on one of the already connected hosts. We need to tell the system about the new machine.

Comment: Just looking at MPI_Info spec answered my question from a previous comment.